# What to set app_host to for Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara, phantomjs, kerberos

My tests attempt to visit webpages and verify that certain elements exist on the pages. For example, it visits `http://foo.com/homepage.html` and checks for a logo image, then visits `http://bar.com/store/blah.html` and checks that certain text appears on the page. My goal is to visit Kerberos authenticated webpages.

I found Kerberos code as below:

**Main file**

```
uri = URI.parse(Capybara.app_host)
kerberos = Kerberos.new(uri.host)
@kerberos_token = kerberos.encoded_token
```

**kerberos.rb file**

```
class Kerberos
    def initialize(host)
      @host = host
      @credentials = AuthGss::Negotiate.new("HTTP@#{@host}")
      @credentials.cache = ENV['KRB5CCNAME'] if ENV['KRB5CCNAME']
      @token = @credentials.step("")
    end

    def encoded_token
      Base64.encode64(@token).gsub(/\n/,"")
    end
  end
```

It utilizes `Capybara.app_host` value. I can't figure out what to set the `Capybara.app_host` value to. I can't figure out what it does. I have `Capybara.run_server = false`. Can someone help me understand how to use `Capybara.app_host` and how this relates to Kerberos authentication?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Capybara docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/tree/2.1.0#calling-remote-servers) show an example of using a remote host. `app_host` is the base host of your web application:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'

visit('/users') # goes to http://www.google.com/users
```

Answer (score 9):

I was confused about `app_host`, but after a dig around in the Capybara source code it seems like it doesn't actually do very much. In fact, it only seems to be used at [one place](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/9dcd6d7546a4ac/lib/capybara/session.rb#L212) in the Capybara source code:

```
if url_relative && Capybara.app_host
  url = Capybara.app_host + url
  url_relative = false
end
```

Basically, if you pass a relative URL like `/posts/1/edit` to a method like `visit`, Capybara will visit the URL "#{Capybara.app_host}/posts/1/edit`. So the following two snippets of code are equivalent:

```
# 1:
Capybara.app_host = "https://stackoverflow.com"
visit "/questions/19991349"

# 2:
visit "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991349"
```

By default RSpec sets `app_host` to  `http://localhost`, which is why you can write code like `before { visit edit_post_path(1) }` when using Capybara and Rails straight out of the box, and you don't have to write `localhost` every time.